# How can I push docSnap.data() into an Array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I have a code:

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

I got data and now, how can I push docSnap.data() into an Array?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean like `array.push( docSnap.data() );`?

Comment: not working. it saves as [object Object] but how can i extract that object data

Comment: what do you mean "it saves"?

Comment: when i conole.log it shows [object Object]

Comment: then try `console.log("%o", array);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but this worked for me:

I first used useState like so

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
        country: "United States",
        state: "California",
        incorporated: "April 15, 1850",
    });
```

Then I pushed the new data into an array like this:

```
           try {
                const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
                if(docSnap.exists()) {
                    let e = docSnap.data()
                    setData((prev) => ({...prev, 
                        country: e.country,
                        state: e.state,
                        incorporated: e.incorporated,
                    }))
                } else {
                    console.log("Document does not exist")
                }
```